# Quando devo usar uma property em vez de um attribute em Python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Se eu definir a classe `Person` abaixo:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name
```

Desta outra forma:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.kind = kind

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self.__name = value
```

Qual a vantagem que tenho? A segunda definição usando property, getter e setter não é a mesma coisa que a primeira definição usando apenas atributos?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sim - você deve usar uma `property` somente - e somente se - o acesso ao atributo envolver algo que vai ser computado ao vivo, e seja mais prático e legível fazer isso com uma atribuição (o operador `=`) do que chamando um método.

Se você não vai modificar, filtrar, testar nada no atributo que está usando, não tem por que criar uma property.

Existe uma cultura - que se desenvolveu de forma equivocada - vinda de outras linguagens orientadas a objeto de que todos os acessos a atributos deveriam ser feitos por 'getters' e 'setters'  - e todos os atributos deveriam ser privados.

Devido as escolhas e design da linguagem Python, em que tudo é aberto, **você não ganha *absolutamente* nada** *ao criar getters e setters extras se não tiver nenhum código relevante dentro dos mesmos*. (As `property` são a forma pythonica de se passar pelos getter e setter mantendo a sintaxe de acesso ao atributo limpa - sem precisar chamar um método.

Então, por exemplo, nesse caso, você poderia usar properties para garantir que o nome sempre seja uma string:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.kind = kind

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, str):
             raise TypeError("...")
        self._name = value
```

mas mesmo esse tipo de checagem -s efor feito em todos os atributos, é meio besta - a ideia é que a linguagem possa aceitar qualquer tipo de parâmetro que funcione para o que ela precisa, e deixe acontecer runtime error se for passado um parâmetro que não funcione. Testar um atributo assim, excepcionalmente é uma coisa - se você estiver testando todos, é hra de rever os conceitos e seu estilo. Em particular, Python atual permite checagem estática de tipos de dados - então você pode criar todo o seu sistema com as  `annotations` corretas e usar o [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/) para verificar se está tudo bem.

**Continuando** - perceba que uma das grandes vantagens da sintaxe de properties é exatamente que qualquer atributo de uma classe pode se transformar num atributo gerenciado por código - isso é, uma property, ou outro tipo de dado  - sem que quem *use* a classe precise mudar nada, nem mesmo saber disso.
Isso é: eu posso criar uma biblioteca que na versão 1.0, os atributos "x" e "y" de uma classe "ponto" sejam atributos de instância normais - e na versão 2.0 da mesma biblioteca transforma-los numa property que  garanta que sejam sempre números - quem usava a versão 1.0 pode continuar usando da mesma forma com  `ponto.x = 10` .

Essa funcionalidade do Python, de fazer o acesso a um atributo passar por código, não é exclusiva das properties - na verdade, ela é definida pelo "protocolo de descritores" (descriptor protocol), e acredito que está melhor documentada no documento chamado ["Data Model"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) da linguagem: qualquer objeto que seja um atributo de classe, e que tenha um método de classe de nome `__get__` vai ser tratado de forma especial quando for acessado como atributo. A `property` é apenas uma classe bastante conveniente para construir esses descritores usando métodos da própria classe para acessar os atributos - mas o mecanismo também é usado para acoplar campos de objetos a colunas de bancos de dados, como no ORM SQLAlchemy ou no ORM do Django, e pelas próprias funções do Python, que usam o mecanismo de descritores para que o atributo `self` seja inserido automaticamente quando elas são usadas como métodos.

**Sobre atributos começando com dois `__`**: Aproveitando o ensejo, não use o prefixo de `__` para seus atributos. Você não ganha nada com isso - isso ativa uma feature da linguagem de mudar o nome real do atributo em tempo de compilação, para evitar colisão de nome nas subclasses - não é algo como um "atributo privado". Na segunda década de existência do Python (mais ou menos de 2000 até 2013) saiu muita documentação - tutoriais, artigos e livros, tratando o prefixo `__` como se fosse o equivalente a atributos privados do Java e C++ - não: atributos privados não existem na sintaxe ou nas especificações de Python. Existem apenas por convenção: isso é, programadores concordam que atributos e métodos começando com *um* (e apenas um) `_` devem ser acessados apenas pelo desenvolvedor de uma classe ou de um módulo, e seu comportamento não precisa ser documentado, e pode estar sujeito a mudanças entre versões de uma biblioteca ou pacote. Mas isso é apenas uma convenção - a linguagem não faz nada para "enforce" isso.
Por outro lado os `__` ativam essa funcionalidade de "name mangling" - que a não ser que você saiba *exatamente* o que quer  e o que esa fazendo, é mais provável que cause um bug dificílimo de entender no seu código do que o que você realmente pretende que aconteça (uma pista: em 18 anos desenvolvendo em Python -  e todo tipo de código avançado e absurdo, eu nunca, nem uma vez, precisei dessa funcionalidade).

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que a resposta é algo bem simples, entenda, em Python, o encapsulamento não segue todas as definições como por exemplo, a linguagem Java, como "private", "public","protected".

Porém, os decoradores fazem isso pra gente.

Veja:

```
class Pessoa(object):
    def __init__(self, name = "Default",idade= 10):
        self._name = name
        self._idade = idade
    
    @property
    def name(self):
        print("Metodo get foi invocado")
        return self._name
    
    
    @name.setter
    def name(self,value):
        print("Metodo set foi invocado")
        self._name = value.title()
    @property
    def idade(self):
        print("Metódo get para o atributo idade foi invocado")
        return self._idade
    @idade.setter
    def idade(self, value):
        print("Metódo set para atributo idade foi invocado")
        self._idade = value.title()
```

neste caso, alguem que utilize nossa classe, quando tentar acessar uma atributo de maneira 'direta' não ira conseguir, a menos que ele queira mesmo.

Nossos decoradores fazem isso pra nós e nossas funções implementam a lógica nescessária.

Ah que legal, mas por que usar? Bem ele deve ser usado para deixar seu código mais limpo, e visualmente melhor de trablhar, em trabalhos em equipe, por exemplo.

Porém pense num caso mais especifico: quando por um acaso precisamos alterar o valor de um atributo, e ele também está no banco de dados, alterar o valor na variável não alterará no nosso banco de dados, certo? logo, poderemos implementar uma lógica, que ao alterar na nossa classe em tempo de execução, ele também altere no nosso banco de dados!.

Comment: O exemplo de tentar manter sincrono o atributo com um armazenamento externo, como o banco de dados, é muito bom.