# Mutador do atributo gerar TypeError caso não receba um número

Tags: python

Estou tentando fazer um tratamento de erro de telefone onde quando é setado algum valor que não seja um número ele lance um `TypeError`.

Alguém pode ver se estou fazendo certo ou onde posso ajustar?

```
from typing import Union, List, Dict

Number = Union[int, float]


class Cliente():
    """
    Classe Cliente do Banco.

    possui os atributos PRIVADOS:
    - nome,
    - telefone,
    - email.
    caso o telefone não seja um número inteiro gera um TypeError
    """

    def __init__(self, nome: str, telefone: int, email: str ):
        self.__nome = nome
        self.__telefone = telefone
        self.__email = email


    def get_nome(self) -> str:
        """Acessor do atributo Nome."""
        return self.__nome

    def get_telefone(self) -> int:
        """Acessor do atributo Telefone."""
        return self.__telefone


    def set_telefone(self, novo_telefone: int) -> None:
        """
        Mutador do atributo telefone, caso não receba um número,
        gera um TypeError
        """
        try: 
            novo_telefone == int
        except TypeError:
            print("Erro: Digite apenas números inteiros")
        else:
            self.__telefone = novo_telefone
            return self.__telefone

Pytest sempre esta retornando string


def test_set_telefone_erro():
    c = Cliente('nome', 99999999, 'email@mail.com')
    try:
        c.set_telefone('não é telefone')
    except TypeError:
        assert True
    except Exception:
        assert False, 'Não lançou um TypeError para telefone inválido'
    else:
        assert c.get_telefone() == 99999999
```

Answer (score 1):

Ao fazer `novo_telefone == int` você está comparando o valor do novo telefone com a própria classe `int` (e nunca serão iguais). Para saber o tipo da variável, uma opção é usar [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
def set_telefone(self, novo_telefone: int) -> None:
    if not isinstance(novo_telefone, int):
        raise TypeError(f"{novo_telefone!r} não é um número inteiro")
    self.__telefone = novo_telefone
```

Ou seja, se o novo telefone é `int`, muda. Senão, lança um `TypeError` (segui o comentário do seu código que diz "caso não receba um número, gera um TypeError"). Repare que o método lança a exceção em caso de dado inválido. Mas você estava tentando capturar a exceção, que no caso não era gerada, por isso nunca caía no `except`.

Também tirei o `return`, pois não faz muito sentido um *setter* retornar o valor que acabou de ser setado (além de ficar condizente com o *type hint*, que indica que a função retorna `None`).

Exemplo de uso:

```
c = Cliente('nome', 99999999, 'email@mail.com')
try:
    c.set_telefone('não é telefone')
except TypeError as e:
    print('Número de telefone não foi alterado:', e)

print(c.get_telefone()) # 99999999
```

Esse código imprime:

```
Número de telefone não foi alterado: 'não é telefone' não é um número inteiro
99999999
```

---

Outro detalhe é que você não está aproveitando a mesma lógica de validação no construtor. Ou seja, na sua classe é possível criar um cliente com um telefone inválido:

```
Cliente('nome', 'abc', 'email@mail.com')
```

Uma alternativa para que a mesma lógica seja reaproveitada é usando *properties*:

```
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, nome: str, telefone: int, email: str ):
        self._nome = nome
        self.telefone = telefone
        self._email = email

    @property
    def telefone(self) -> int:
        return self._telefone

    @telefone.setter
    def telefone(self, novo_telefone: int) -> None:
        if not isinstance(novo_telefone, int):
            raise TypeError(f"{novo_telefone!r} não é um número inteiro")
        self._telefone = novo_telefone

c = Cliente('nome', 99999999, 'email@mail.com')
try:
    c.telefone = 'não é telefone'
except TypeError as e:
    print('Número de telefone não foi alterado:', e)
```

Assim, o `TypeError` também é lançado ao tentar criar um cliente com telefone inválido (ou seja, `Cliente('nome', 'abc', 'email@mail.com')` também lança a exceção).

Não criei as *properties* para o nome e email, mas baseando-se no código acima, não será difícil fazê-lo.

Para saber mais sobre `property`, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/375796/112052) (este link também dá uma ótima explicação para não usar os nomes dos campos começando com dois `_` - repare no código acima que mudei para usar apenas um `_`).

---

Dito isso, telefones não são números inteiros. São informações que por acaso usam dígitos, o que é bem diferente.

Por exemplo, se eu tratar os dados como números, então `80012345678` e `080012345678` são o mesmo número: ambos representam o mesmo valor numérico, já que o zero à esquerda não faz diferença (e na verdade, se você tentar usar `set_telefone(0800)`, vai dar erro porque `0800` não é um [literal numérico válido](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#numeric-literals)).

Mas `80012345678` e `080012345678` são telefones completamente diferentes. Os zeros à esquerda fazem diferença (tente discar para um serviço 0800 sem colocar o zero na frente e não funcionará). Há também casos de telefones com letras (não é tão comum no Brasil, mas em outros países sim), códigos DDI costumam ter o `+` na frente (`+5511999991234`), etc. Sendo assim, o telefone deveria ser uma string, e não um número.